# Setting up Android emulator to use sensor data from real Android device

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sensors

From [Android developer doc on using emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html):

> Android emulator supports sensors like an accelerometer, using data
>   from a USB-connected Android device.

However, I couldn't find further details on how to set up such test bed.

Could you help me with some insight?